# Fiscal Month Start Dates

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a fiscal Month End date column. Based on this column I will have to calculate 12 month prior fiscal start date, 24 month prior fiscal start date and so on.

I cannot use add_months function here as below are the fscl month end dates. When a user chooses 01-JUL-2017, the 12 months prior date should start at 03-JUL-16.

If I use add months the date range would change to be 01-JUL-2016 to 01-JUL-2017 but I need it to be 03-JUL-2017 to 01-JUL-2017.

```
FISCAL MONTH END DATES
30-JAN-16
27-FEB-16
02-APR-16
30-APR-16
28-MAY-16
02-JUL-16
30-JUL-16
27-AUG-16
01-OCT-16
29-OCT-16
26-NOV-16
28-JAN-17
25-FEB-17
01-APR-17
29-APR-17
27-MAY-17
01-JUL-17
```

Comment: Please let me know if my answer below was useful and accept the same.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your table has all the dates in the sequence, You can use the LAG function with parameter 11 (i.e. 11th previous date in the sequence).Take the user input from the where clause as a bind Variable. 
( WHERE TO_CHAR(DT,'DD-MON-YY') = :curr_fiscal_end_dt )

```
      SELECT Prev_fisc_start_date FROM 
           (
              SELECT DT, LAG(DT, 11 )  OVER ( ORDER BY DT ) + 1 Prev_fisc_start_dt FROM 
                Your_table

           ) WHERE TO_CHAR(DT,'DD-MON-YY') ='01-JUL-2017';
```